# Best way to encrypt a directory of files?

Tags: java, .net, c++, python, encryption

I need to programatically encrypt a directory of files, like in a .zip or whatever.  Preferably password protected obviously.

How can I accomplish this, and WHAT IS the BEST  encryption way to do it, if applicable?

Programming language doesn't matter.  I am dictioned in all syntax.

Comment: Much better.  Thanks for wasting out time on your old question...

Comment: Also, best is an ambiguous term.  Are you looking for smallest compressed size?  Speed of encryption?  Strength of encryption?

Comment: ...and what resources do you need to protect against what attacks, and what are you willing to trust? Specifically, who may have access to the encrypted files, and for how long a period of time are they sensitive? Some data is sensitive only for a period of hours, days or months (a lot of commercial data), whereas no firm time limit can be placed on other data (e.g. personal integrity). Use the appropriate mechanism, but don't think that encryption alone gives you security: consider both how you do decryption, and how you store your key.

Comment: This is not a good programming question since the "best" way to encrypt your files is to use any of the widely available utilities (for various operating systems) or even any of the available hardware (with embedded encryption support) which have already been written to perform this very function.

Thus this is a question that would be FAR better suited to server fault or super user than to SO.

The simplest approach would be to create an archive (tar, zip, whatever you like) and then to use GPG/PGP on the result.  However, that's basically off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I accomplish this, and WHAT IS
>   the BEST encryption way to do it, if
>   applicable?

- tar and gzip the directory.
- Generate a random bit stream of equal size to the file
- Run bitwise XOR on the streams

Only truly secure method is a truly random one time pad.

Comment: The best way to encrypt data is to place the hard drive into a hydraulic press (as long as decryption is not a requirement).

Comment: Before I recommend XOR ... I generally express a preference for double-ROT-13 (twice as secure, convenient, and fast, as the original ROT-13)!

Comment: If you are going to go for double rot you might as well go for triple rot 13 for even more security.

Answer (score 3):

I still say 7-zip is the answer. It hasn't been "cracked".

Comment: Now he is asking for a programatic way.  Is there a 7zip api available?

Comment: There is an SDK for 7-zip (http://7-zip.org/sdk.html), but I don't know if it includes encryption support out-of-the box. It wouldn't be hard to just zip the files and then run your own encryption on them, of course.

Comment: It doesn't look like the SDK/API for 7-Zip currently includes encryption -- but you can get that (along with compression) by interfacing to it through that application's command line interface from any programming language that supports running external executables. I done exactly that with Python.

Answer (score 3):

The **OpenSSL** library has a variety of block cipher implementations including the well-known AES.  It has both a function-call interface (for use with languages like C/C++) and a program-call interface (for use in shell scripts).  http://www.openssl.org/

Answer (score 3):

**4096**-Bit (**Open**)PGP: '**Pretty Good**' *Privacy* !

> GnuPG is the GNU project's complete and free implementation of the OpenPGP standard as defined by RFC4880 . GnuPG allows to encrypt and sign your data and communication, features a versatile key managment system as well as access modules for all kind of public key directories. GnuPG, also known as GPG, is a command line tool with features for easy integration with other applications. A wealth of frontend applications and libraries are available. Version 2 of GnuPG also provides support for S/MIME.

libgcrypt:
http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/libraries.en.html

**Edit:**
BouncyCastle now has OpenPGP support.
http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). You'll find implementations in your favourite programming language by asking google for `AES encryption + myfavouritelanguage`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET, why not use a free compression framework (http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) that supports Encryption?